# How to initialize database with some data when app startup? (fastapi, sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm new to the fastapi and sqlalchemy. And I'm trying to initialize some data when I startup my app. Here is what I'm thinking of:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    with SessionLocal() as session:
        country_dataframe = pd.read_csv('./initialize_data/country.csv')
        for index, row in country_dataframe.iterrows():
            session.add(models.Country(row.to_dict()))
        session.commit()
```

But I can't get the db session when I start it, it shows an error code:

> ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\newia\Miniconda3\envs\fastapi\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py",
> line 540, in lifespan
> async for item in self.lifespan_context(app):   File "C:\Users\newia\Miniconda3\envs\fastapi\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py",
> line 481, in default_lifespan
> await self.startup()   File "C:\Users\newia\Miniconda3\envs\fastapi\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py",
> line 516, in startup
> await handler()   File "D:\Software Projects\PythonProjects\LanguageExchange\app.py", line 27, in
> startup_event
> with SessionLocal() as session: AttributeError: **enter**
>
> ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.

Is there any design pattern to do this? Any advice would be grateful.

Comment: did you try without async?

Comment: What is `SessionLocal`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Usually you'd want to [use `alembic` to perform any migrations](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/), that way you avoid repeatedly inserting data each time your application starts if it has already been inserted before. You then run alembic before starting FastAPI to make sure the database is up to speed (or you can run alembic programmatically from your startup event handler).

Comment: You can check this starter fast API [template](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql). I think the section you be interested in the [init_db.py](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend/app/app/db/init_db.py)

Comment: @I.Lin I'm not sure what you're asking about, but the easiest way is to run `alembic upgrade head` in a script that launches uvicorn/gunicorn/etc. afterwards.